# Convert 16bit QImage to 8bit unsigned char in QT

Tags: c++, image, qt, image-processing

I am trying to figure out how to convert an image from uint16 to uint8. I am basically having to read the image in float, and I need to display it in unsigned char.

I have the following:

```
   float two_eight =  pow(2.0,8);
   float two_sixteen = pow(2.0,16);
    QImage *qi = new QImage(imwidth, imheight, QImage::Format_RGB32);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < imheight ; i++)
        {
             for (int j = 0 ; j < imwidth ; j++)
             {
                    floatData[i*imwidth+j] = (two_eight* floatData[i*imwidth+j])/two_sixteen;
                    qi->setPixel(j,i,qRgb((unsigned char)floatData[i*imwidth+j],(unsigned char)floatData[i*imwidth+j],(unsigned char)floatData[i*imwidth+j]));


             }
         }
```

Is there a better way of performing this in Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you got an image in RGB format where each color component is 16 bits, and you want to load this using QImage.

You can do it like this :

```
std::vector< unsigned short int > inData;
// load the data into a vector
std::vector< unsigned char > outData( inData.size(), 0 );
std::transfrorm( inData.begin(), inData.end(), outData.begin(), Convert );
// create the image object
QImage image( &outData[0],imwidth, imheight, QImage::Format_RGB32 );
```

where the `Convert` function is defined like this :

```
unsigned char Convert( const unsigned short int v )
{
  return v >> 8;
}
```

Comment: QImage doesn't support 16 bit per channel images :)

Comment: @vines I know, that is why I first convert 16-bit data (stored in `inData` vector) to 8-bit data (`outData` vector), before creating QImage using 8-bit data.

Comment: +1 for a decent answer, however, it turns out my actual problem was that the actual bits per pixel being used was 11. It was allocated in a 16 bit structure though, so that is pretty annoying.

Answer (score 1):

imdata is your 16bit image buffer

```
#include <cstdint>    
uint16_t *imdata;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < imheight ; ++i)
            {
                 //preincrement, is faster than post
                 for (int j = 0 ; j < imwidth ; ++j)
                 {
                        //imdata[i*imwidth+j]>>8 removes least significant 8bits
                        //imdata has one added to adjust for components
                        qi->setPixel(j,i,qRgb((uint8_t)(imdata[i*imwidth+j]>>8),(uint8_t)(imdata[i*imwidth+j+1]>>8),(uint8_t)(imdata[i*imwidth+j+2]>>8)));


                 }
             }
```

Comment: preincrement is faster than post?! Of course - if the compiler has no permission to do some easy optimzations. For production code, compiled on common compilers, there will be no difference in the binary.

Comment: I also think it looks nicer so I do it subconsciously ;)  On top of that we do not know what compiler is being used. I have notice this little change make a provable difference on LLVM and GCC compilers and its not like pre increment can ever be any slower.

Comment: It will be faster then what is posted in the question - for sure. But you are still setting pixel per pixel in 2 for loops. That is what is also bad with this approach

Comment: even with `-OS` or `-O2`? If speed really is relevant: `i < imheight` in regular `for`-loops can be exchanged with `i != imheight`. Thus you usually spare one substraction on assembler level.